# Sliding Navigation Bar - How Did They Do It?

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, navbar, sliding

I am trying to figure out how to get this sliding navigator bar effect: http://manoscrafted.com/. I can get as far as fixing the top hero image and sliding the bottom nav bar up and down, however, it doesn't stick to the top.

Is this done through JavaScript or am I missing something in CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: they are using this plugin http://code.google.com/p/sticky-panel/

Answer (score 0):

Achieved using JavaScript, most people would call this "parallax" scrolling with a "fixed" or "sticky" header/navigation

See parallax examples:

http://ihatetomatoes.net/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website/

See sticky/fixed examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/2jqCA/

```
var win      = $(window),
    fxel     = $('nav'),
    eloffset = fxel.offset().top;

win.scroll(function() {
    if (eloffset < win.scrollTop()) {
        fxel.addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        fxel.removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! I'm not too familiar with JavaScript. Instead of using the tag "nav", if I wanted to use a class, could I just do $('.header'),? Then in regards to fxel.addClass("fixed"); would I create a new class in my css for .header.fix?

Comment: The short answer is yes.  The long answer is when you start changing things you may need to change others things to get everything to work again ;)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to figure it out. It doesn't work yet but I do get a quick like flash when I scroll. Hopefully I'm on the right track.